# Как в запросе SQL отфильтровать с ограничением по количеству?

Tags: sql, mysql

В общем суть задачи такова:
Есть таблица в которой есть поле name с различными значениями, нужно чтобы в результирующую выборку попало 5 строк у которых name=masha и 3 строки где name=dasha. Все это нужно сделать одним SELECT, без всяких UNION. Как это можно сделать никак не соображу, то ли фильтрацией, то ли сортировкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @s=0;set @m=0;
select name from (
select case when name='sasha' then @s:=@s+1 else @m:=@m+1 end x, @s s,@m m, name 
from t where name in('sasha','masha')
) x
where (m<=5 and x=m) or (s<=3 and s=x);
```